Task :intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources FAILED
I recently upgraded our app several React Native versions from 0.70.x -> 74.x and after this effort I am now receiving the following error from Intercom on Android (fwiw iOS runs fine):
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\repos\Opendorse-Mobile\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources' (type 'MergeResources').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\repo\node_modules\@intercom\intercom-react-native\android\build\generated\res\resValues\debug'.

    Reason: Task ':intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources' uses this output of task ':intercom-react-native:generateDebugResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':intercom-react-native:generateDebugResValues' as an input of ':intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':intercom-react-native:generateDebugResValues' from ':intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':intercom-react-native:generateDebugResValues' from ':intercom_intercom-react-native:packageDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter.

    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 38s
102 actionable tasks: 100 executed, 2 up-to-date

0.70.x -> 74.x contained some pretty massive architectural changes to some native files. So I imagine the issue is stemming from somewhere within my gradle implementation, but after much debugging I haven't been able to narrow into it yet. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!
Things I have tried:

Nearly every possible combo of task declaration via the "Possible solutions". I can get past the immediate error, but it opens up dozens more similar ones (which makes me think there is something fundamentally wrong with my gradle implementation or version somewhere)
Version Upgrades and downgrades of react-native, Gradle, Kotlin, etc.
Ensuring I have everything effectively the same source code as the example app they provided (which I DID get to run)
Going back and the forth with the Intercom team (they have not provided much insight)
Tweaking the gradle files in just about everyway possible

